# differentiate and solve $A = \frac{200}r + 3\pi r^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> differentiate and solve $A = \frac{200}r + 3\pi r^2$

$A = 200r^{-1} + 3\pi r^2$

$A' = 6\pi r - 200r^{-2}$

$6\pi r - 200r^{-2} = 0$

From here I am not sure how to solve the equation with negative exponents.

Comment: Use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

Comment: it is equivalent to $6\pi r^3-200=0$ with $r \ne 0$

Comment: @Programmer400 "Use the chain rule" What for?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to differentiate. For A=0 then, you simplify the expression:

$3\pi r^3=100$

Geometrically it looks like r is the radius of a sphere. The chain rule is used because -r=f(r) where f'(r) = -1, therefore the negative sign in front of the constant when we differentiate.

Comment: What chain rule?

Comment: I don't see how the chain rule applies to this expression.  Could you please outline the steps.

Answer (score 0):

your equation is: $$ 6\pi r - 200r^{-2} = 0$$
multiply both sides by $ r^2$:$$6\pi r^3=200$$
now you get $r^3=200/6\pi$

Comment: pleaseaccept an answer or give an upvote if my answer has helped you @dagda1